# How to store data of a symmetric matrix table?

Tags: javascript, matrix

I will try to explain my problem as best as possible. I need to store some data in a similar way as a matrix table but with code.

Let's take for example a simple table:

[image]

The first idea that I had for this would be to create a JS object storing all the possibilities like this:

```
const Y = 'Yellow';
const R = 'Red';
const W = 'White';
const P = 'Pink';

const data = {
   Y: { Y: Y, R: Y, W: Y },
   R: { Y: Y, R: R, W: P }, 
   W: { Y: Y, R: P, W: W }
};

console.log(data['W']['R']); // 'Pink'
```

But considering the fact that **I will have much more possibilities**, this is obviously not maintenable.

I can also reduce the size of the object like this, but again I am afraid that it would be hard to maintain:

```
const data = {
   Y: { Y: Y, R: Y, W: Y },
   R: { R: R, W: P }, 
   W: { W: W }
};
```

**The problem sounds simple but I cannot find another the way to store such data. Is there a better way to do this?**

---

Also, I would like to add that I used JS here because I am more familiar with this language but I will have to use this with PHP, just in case it makes a big difference.

Comment: would an 2d array work? what do you mean with *code*?

Comment: Just my two cents - I don't see why it isn't maintainable or you're worried about the size. Unless you're working on something with extremely limited storage I would go with whatever is clearest to you. And that seems quite clear - like pulling cells from a spreadsheet.

Comment: how is the access to the data? from the outside, like `data['W']['R']`? why is it a not maintainable structure? do you need to save space or do you need faster access (as objects or maps)?

Comment: the order does not matter, that's data['W']['R'] === data['R']['W']. you may have some reasons to have a matrix. I would have this in a map. Just my 2 cents worth

Comment: @dgig @Nina Scholz I was honestly thinking that I was doing it wrong and that something was already existing to store such data. I am a bit afraid about the maintainability because I don't know yet how many data I will have in this table. I don't necessarily need it to be fast nor I need space though I have to keep is flexible. And yes, I will get the results with something similar to `data['W']['R']` @D. Seah I don't know in which order I will receive the two letters, though, maybe organising my data by alphabetical order might help. Thank you all for your help.

Comment: maybe you want to edit the title adding "symmetric"?

Comment: @WalterTross  Edit done !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most compact representation of all, which I don't recommend unless you really are short of space, is that of a triangular matrix in a single array.

```
function triMatrix(n) { // not really needed
    return new Array(n * (n + 1) / 2);
}

function trindex(row, col) {
    if (col > row) {
        var tmp = row; row = col; col = tmp;
    }
    return row * (row + 1) / 2 + col;
}

function triStore(tri, indexOfKey, rowKey, colKey, value) {
    tri[trindex(indexOfKey[rowKey], indexOfKey[colKey])] = value;
}

function triGet(tri, indexOfKey, rowKey, colKey) {
    return tri[trindex(indexOfKey[rowKey], indexOfKey[colKey])];
}

const keyOfIndex = ['Y', 'R', 'W'];
const indexOfKey = {'Y': 0, 'R': 1, 'W': 2}; // can be calculated
const N = keyOfIndex.length;
var tri = triMatrix(N); // could also be var tri = [];
triStore(tri, indexOfKey, 'Y', 'Y', 'Y');
triStore(tri, indexOfKey, 'Y', 'R', 'Y');
triStore(tri, indexOfKey, 'Y', 'W', 'Y');
triStore(tri, indexOfKey, 'R', 'R', 'R');
triStore(tri, indexOfKey, 'R', 'W', 'P');
triStore(tri, indexOfKey, 'W', 'W', 'W');
tri; // => [ "Y", "Y", "R", "Y", "P", "W" ]
triGet(tri, indexOfKey, 'R', 'W'); // => "P"
triGet(tri, indexOfKey, 'W', 'R'); // => "P"
```

The point is: your matrix is symmetric, so you only need either its upper or its lower triangular matrix (including the diagonal). In your proposal you store the upper triangular matrix, in mine I store the lower one because index calculation is much simpler. The array will contain the 1st row of 1 element, the 2nd of 2, the 3rd of 3, etc. Just remember that 1+2+...+n=n(n+1)/2 and you'll understand how the array index is calculated.

```
M₀₀ M₀₁ M₀₂      M₀₀              T₀
M₁₀ M₁₁ M₁₂  =>  M₁₀ M₁₁      =>  T₁  T₂      =>  T₀ T₁ T₂ T₃ T₄ T₅
M₂₀ M₂₁ M₂₂      M₂₀ M₂₁ M₂₂      T₃  T₄  T₅
```

The matrix is easily extended by 1 row/column, no reindexing of the array is necessary:

```
M₀₀ M₀₁ M₀₂ M₀₃      M₀₀                  T₀
M₁₀ M₁₁ M₁₂ M₁₃      M₁₀ M₁₁              T₁  T₂
M₂₀ M₂₁ M₂₂ M₂₃  =>  M₂₀ M₂₁ M₂₂      =>  T₃  T₄  T₅      => T₀ ... T₆ T₇ T₈ T₉
M₃₀ M₃₁ M₃₂ M₃₃      M₃₀ M₃₁ M₃₂ M₃₃      T₆  T₇  T₈  T₉
```

---

As an excercise I loosely translated the above to PHP, which is your target language. Even though I started by not recommending the “triangular matrix in a single array” approach, you are welcome to use the following class as a black box, if it matches your needs (and if it doesn't, maybe I can help).

```
class SymmetricMatrix
{
    private $n = 0;
    private $triangular = [];
    private $key_of_index = [];
    private $index_of_key = [];

    private function add_key_if_necessary($key) {
        if ( !isset($this->index_of_key[$key])) {
            $index = $this->n++;
            $this->index_of_key[$key] = $index;
            $this->key_of_index[$index] = $key;
            for ($i = 0; $i < $this->n; $i++) {
                $this->triangular[] = false; // avoid "jumping" index & init to "absent"
            }
        }
    }

    private static function trindex($row, $col) {
        if ($col > $row) {
            $tmp = $row; $row = $col; $col = $tmp;
        }
        return $row * ($row + 1) / 2 + $col;
    }

    public function put($key1, $key2, $value) {
        $this->add_key_if_necessary($key1);
        $this->add_key_if_necessary($key2);
        $trindex = self::trindex($this->index_of_key[$key1], $this->index_of_key[$key2]);
        $this->triangular[$trindex] = $value;
    }

    public function get($key1, $key2) {
        if (!isset($this->index_of_key[$key1]) || !isset($this->index_of_key[$key2])) {
            return false;
        }
        $trindex = self::trindex($this->index_of_key[$key1], $this->index_of_key[$key2]);
        return $this->triangular[$trindex];
    }

    public function find_first($value) { // $value !== false
        for ($row = 0; $row < $this->n; $row++) {
            for ($col = 0; $col <= $row; $col++) {
                $trindex = trindex($row, $col);
                if ($this->triangular[$trindex] === $value) {
                    return [$this->key_of_index[$row], $this->key_of_index[$col]];
                }
            }
        }
        return false;
    }

    public function get_keys() {
        return $this->key_of_index;
    }

    public function dump() {
        var_export($this);
        echo "\n";
    }
}

$m = new SymmetricMatrix();
$m->put('Y', 'Y', 'Y');
$m->put('Y', 'R', 'Y');
$m->put('Y', 'W', 'Y');
$m->put('R', 'R', 'R');
$m->put('R', 'W', 'P');
$m->put('W', 'W', 'W');
$m->dump();
echo "keys: ", implode(', ', $m->get_keys()), "\n";
echo "m[R][W]: ", $m->get('R', 'W'), "\n";
echo "m[W][R]: ", $m->get('W', 'R'), "\n";
```

Comment: These codes look really interesting ! I am not sure to understand why you decided to pass `tri` and `indexOfKey` as a parameters for `triStore` and `triGet` instead of using the variables directly ? I haven't had the time to check everything in detail yet but I am pretty sure both your JS and PHP codes will help me. Thank you !

Comment: oh, that was only to keep the functions generic and reusable - just a useful habit